# Get redux-form valid property from parent component

Tags: redux-form

I have my submit button outside the 'reduxForm' component
How can i disable the button if the form is invalid?

```
<MainComponent><MyForm/><MyButton disabled={???}/></MainComponent>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `isValid` or `isInvalid` selectors.

> isValid(formName:String) returns (state) => valid:boolean
>   Returns true if the form is valid, i.e. has no sync, async, or submission errors. The opposite of isInvalid.
>
> isInvalid(formName:String) returns (state) => invalid:boolean Returns
>   true if the form is invalid, i.e. has sync, async, or submission
>   errors. The opposite of isValid.

```
import {
  isValid,
  isInvalid
} from 'redux-form'

MyComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    valid: isValid('myForm')(state),
    invalid: isInvalid('myForm')(state)
  })
)(MyComponent)
```

And in your render function use it to disable button:

```
<MainComponent><MyForm/><MyButton disabled={this.props.invalid}/></MainComponent>
```